# Pack npm files independent of their directory?

Tags: npm

I have an npm project that builds multiple files to the public folder: an index.js file as well as several sub-files that I want to be conveniently accessible to the implementer.

My file structure on my machine looks like this:

```
|-public/
|--- index.js
|--- component1.js
|--- component2.js
```

My package.json is set up to include everything in the public folder in its tarball:

```
{
    ...
    "main": "public/index.js",
    "files": [ "public" ]
    ...
}
```

When I run the npm pack command, the resulting structure of the tarball looks like this:

```
|- package/
|--- public/
|------ index.js
|------ component1.js
|------ component2.js
|--- package.json
```

But in my package folder, I'd like everything to be on the same root level so that my implementer can just type `import Component1 from "my-package-name/component1";` to get the sub-component. Is there a way to configure my package.json or npm to pack my project into the following structure?

```
|- package/
|--- index.js
|--- component1.js
|--- component2.js
|--- package.json
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up accomplishing this by moving my `package.json` file to my `/public` folder, then packing and publishing from that folder instead, then moving `package.json`back. If you can automate this process with a script, it is not too much of an inconvenience.